# How do I convert days into years and months in python?

Tags: python

How do I convert days into years and months and days in python?
for example: if someone were to be 5,538 days old. how can I display that through years and months and days like this : 15 years old 2 months and 1 day

## this is to get user's input

```
print "Please enter your birthday"
bd_year = int(raw_input("Year: "))
bd_month = int(raw_input("Month: "))
bd_day = int(raw_input("Day: "))

from datetime import date
now = date.today()

birthdate = date(int(bd_year), int(bd_month), int(bd_day))
age_in_days = now - birthdate

print "Your age is %s" % age_in_days
```

## now I need to calculate the person's birthday in years and months and days

Comment: Didn't the user already give you that?

Comment: Perhaps they meant "the person's _age_ in years/etc."?

Comment: looks like @hollyliu wants to calculate a person's age in days alone, eg 3,650ish for a 10 year old. What is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about using `dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta` from the [`dateutil` library](https://labix.org/python-dateutil)? For example:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
rdelta = relativedelta(now, birthdate)
print 'Age in years - ', rdelta.years
print 'Age in months - ', rdelta.months
print 'Age in days - ', rdelta.days
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta` is very efficient here: Except for using `.months` or `.days`.

because rdelta.months gives you the remaining months after using full years, it doesn't give you the actual difference in months.
You should convert years to months if you need to see the difference in months.

```
def deltamonths(x):
       rdelta = relativedelta(now, birthdate)
       return rdelta.years*12 + rdelta.months
```