# unsupported operand type(s) for %

Tags: python, module, int

```
today = date.today()                       
expire_date = date(today.year, 6, 7)       

days = expire_date - today
left_months = days // 30            
left_days = days % 30  
'''
Error in this line : unsupported operand type(s) for %: 
                                    'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'
'''  
print('{} Months'.format(left_months), '{} Days'.format(left_days) + " until exhibition day")
```

Comment: I dont understand what you're trying to do. Not all months have 30 days. It would be easier if you just did this in a self-contained way using just datetimes, not trying to divide through (IIUC)

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory.  `days` is a `timedelta` object, and it makes no sense to perform integer modulo on such an object.  (I'm a bit surprised that the integer division worked.) What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: If you want the number of days in the timedelta, use the `.days` attribute: `left_days = days.days % 30`

Comment: I want to calculate a counter to a specific date that says how many months and days have left.
@JohnGordon

Comment: This looks like an example of choosing a poor variable name.  When you call the timedelta object by the name `days`, you trick yourself into thinking that it is a simple integer, when it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the answer to [How do I convert days into years and months in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083726/how-do-i-convert-days-into-years-and-months-in-python), you can use the package [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
expire_date = date(today.year, 6, 7)

rdelta = relativedelta(expire_date, today)

print(f'{rdelta.months} months {rdelta.days} days until exhibition day')
```

Also notice the usage of [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), as they are  I believe more *pythonic*.