# Calculate age in day, month and year from birth date and a specific day using python

Tags: python, datetime, calculated-columns

I have dataframe of medical services performed in a city. I would like to get the age of the individuals served based on the two columns: the birth date column and the service date column. I am using python (google colaboratory).

my dataframe is something like this:

```
name dob          attendance_day 
AB   2016-04-09   2017-01-01
CD   2010-07-21   2018-12-30
EF   2017-11-25   2018-12-31
```

And I need to calculate da **age of individuals** in **day, month and year**.

I have tried this:

input:

```
data['age'] = data['attendance_date'] - data['birth_date']
data['age'] = data['age'].dt.days
data['age'] = data['age']//365.25 #convert days into years
```

output:

```
name   dob          attendance_day  age 
    AB   2016-04-09   2017-01-01      267
    CD   2010-07-21   2018-12-30      2908  
    EF   2017-11-25   2018-12-31      401
```

So, I got the age in days. But I need the age in day, month and year. Is there some code to do that?

Comment: OK, so what error messages do you get, or how is the outcome not what you expect it to be?

Comment: and what is format of `data['attendance_date']` and `data['birth_date']` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083726/how-do-i-convert-days-into-years-and-months-in-python

Comment: I think I can answer it but can you provide a few examples of data rows?

Comment: @Sherlock70 the outcome is in days, I would like a way to transform this to day, month and year... or, another code that makes this transformation directly....

Comment: @PooyaEstakhri both are datetime64[ns]

Comment: @OferSadan yes, I just rephrased the question ... see if it's better now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

First import this library:

```
from datetime import date
```

Convert Days into Years:

```
def calculateAge(birthDate):
    today = date.today()
    age = today.year - birthDate.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (birthDate.month, birthDate.day))
    return age
```

Driver code:

```
print(calculateAge(date(1999, 8, 7)), "years")
```

Output:

```
22 years
```

Or Try this:

```
from datetime import date
DOB = date(1999, 8, 7)
today = date.today()
time_difference = today - DOB
D = time_difference.days
M = int((D/365)*12)
Y = int(D/365)
print(f"Years: {Y}")
print(f"Months: {M}")
print(f"Days: {D}")
```

Output:

```
Years: 22
Months: 264
Days: 8050
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you could make some if else conditions if you want to display the age in years months and days. for example, a person's age is 20 years 3 months and 4 days, the way I did it was a very primitive way which can be improvised to a great extent. I took the dob as an input from the user taking the date month and year of his birth individually. Similarly, I assigned individual variables the values of current day month and year. The second task was to simply subtract the years, but be careful making conditions subtracting the months and days, for example, if dob is for june and currently it is february, it will display the month as a negative number, thus you can adjust this by decreasing the year difference by one, and implementing a logic using conditional statements to display the period of the months and making a similar adjustments for the day difference as well. Also be careful while making day adjustments as months vary having 30, 31 and 28 or 29 days. The leap year concept might make it tricky, as much as I can think, but this should solve your problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is somewhat similar to what you're looking for:

```
from datetime import date

def age_calculator(birth):
    today = date.today()
    days = (today - birth).days
    months = 0
    years = 0
    while days >= 365.25:
        days -= 365.25
        years += 1
    while days >= 30.55:
        days -= 30.55
        months += 1
    return f'You are {years} years, {months} months and {int(days)} days old.'

user_year = int(input('Enter your birth year: '))
user_month = int(input('Enter the number of your birth month: '))
user_day = int(input('Enter your birth day: '))

print(age_calculator(date(user_year, user_month, user_day)))
```

I was checking if it's accurate and in some dates there is one day of inaccuracy... but I can't bother with figuring it out lol.